# Name of Power Cord Attachment Piece

Tags: laptop, power, cable

I recently purchased an Acer laptop and the power cord uses a piece that is different than a Velcro strap to wrap the cord up. I can't figure out what the name of this piece is. I've included an image of what I am talking about below.

[image: What is this called?]

Comment: Cable manager?  Cable clip?  I too await the real answer.

Comment: Although far from an authoritative source, this [lifehacker article](https://lifehacker.com/5791354/get-better-control-over-your-macbooks-power-cord-with-its-built-in-wrapping-clip) calls it a "built-in wrapping clip" when referring to a similar clip that comes on a MacBook. I'm not sure that there's any official name for it.